# Centos System config language not working

Tags: linux, utf-8, centos5

I am using Centos 5.x. I have set the system-config-language in /etc/sysconfig/i18n file as

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

But when i type echo $LANG it shows as :

```
fr_FR.UTF_8
```

Please let me know where can i change the settings so that i will get English language as default.

Thanks
Rajasekhar

Comment: You have made the configuration, but not loaded it. Try restarting the system after making the changes, if you can.

Comment: @skrtbhtngr Ofcourse I have done that boss, still problem is there.

Comment: Probably something in your personal `.bashrc` or similar is overriding the global setting.  See e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36762/where-is-the-system-profile-that-gets-sourced-at-login-on-centos-5-8 for some pointers to files to look at.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the reply, it worked.Make it as answer i will mark it.

Comment: Without proper diagnostics, this is pure guesswork.  This is not a programming question, anyway.  But feel free to post a detailed description of how you fixed the problem as an answer yourself, and accept it so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. (You may have to wait before you can click the big friendly check mark to accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the `source` command on the file:

`source /etc/sysconfig/i18n`